# Taking input from user when usb device is plugged in

Tags: linux, bash, unix, permissions, udev

I am running a script when a USB device is plugged in using udev rules (RUN Command) and display a notification using notify-send.

I want it to prompt user to enter some inputs to the USB.  How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Since the X session you are running is unknown to udev, udev has no idea who to send to and X could have more then one active session running. And for Zenity type of script to work you also need X-Auth cookie from the current X session being running. Which is now change from home to a temp location which you will not have a fix script to hack around that.

There are lots of way to do what you need but it depend on how much work you want to do.

notify-send only display information so it is not going to work. Like the above suggestion you need zenity or kdialog type for the input. But more importantly you need the current session, so you may want to hook your script with gnome-session-properties. That way your hooking will be run every time you login.

This is just one way to hook to the gnome-session-propoties

```
#!/bin/sh 

mkfifo /tmp/usb_notify
mkfifo /tmp/usb_feedback

while ( true ) do {
    CALLBACK=`cat /tmp/usb_notify`
    # check CALLBACK for some specific password :) if you needed 
    notify-send "USB plugged in something, input something for me!";
    USERINPUT=$(zenity --entry --title "USB plugged in" --text "Please enter something")
    echo $USERINPUT > /tmp/usb_feedback 
} done;
```

Then you can hook this in the udev RUN for you usb device

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "password" > /tmp/usb_notify 
REPLY=`cat /tmp/usb_feedback` 
# then you can do whatever you need to with the feedback
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use zenity. In your shell script:

USERINPUT=$(zenity --entry --title "USB plugged in" --text "Please enter something")

For a complete reference see: http://library.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/

There is also a KDE-couterpart called kdialog.